# Form with icon on Bootstrap v3.1.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons

I cannot show double icon bootstrap v3.1.1. when I using old version bootstrap with class "icon-user" its work but not for glyphicon icon bootstrap v3.1.1

```
<div class="col-xs-6" >
<div class="left-inner-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control" 
           placeholder="Username" />
    <br>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control" 
           placeholder="password" />
    <br>    
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

css for style

```
 .left-inner-addon {
  position: relative;
  }

.left-inner-addon input {
  padding-left: 30px;    
 }

 .left-inner-addon i {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  }

 .right-inner-addon {
   position: relative;
 }

 .right-inner-addon input {
  padding-right: 30px;    
 }

 .right-inner-addon i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.btn-primary
{
 width:100%;
}
```

code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/426/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is both glyicons apply to the same first input. You can fix this by simply having 2 div's.

```
<div class="left-inner-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Username" />
</div>
<div class="left-inner-addon">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="password" />
        <br>    
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">

 </div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/428/